# Error dependencies when deploy on Wildfly 10

Tags: java, spring-mvc, wildfly-10

My Project structure like this:

opm-common:
   |_opm-api:
   |_opm-portal:

These are opm file:

opm-common

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.chick</groupId>
<artifactId>opm-common</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.1.1</version>
<name>Online Project Management Common</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>      
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jackson.version>2.7.3</jackson.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.9.4</joda-time.version>        
    <spring-data>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data>
</properties>
...
    <build>
        <finalName>opm-common</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>          
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

opm-api

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.chick</groupId>
    <artifactId>opm-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
    <name>Online Project Management API</name>

    <properties>            
        <opm.common.version>0.1.1</opm.common.version>      
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.37</mysql.version>       
        <mongo.version>3.2.2</mongo.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- OPM dependencies  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.chick</groupId>
            <artifactId>opm-common</artifactId>
            <version>${opm.common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...     
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>opm-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                       <Dependencies>com.chick.opm-common</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                 </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>       
         <id>default</id>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.6</version>
                  <configuration>
                     <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
       </profile>
       <profile>    
         <id>openshift</id>
         <build>
            <finalName>opm-api</finalName>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                  <warName>opm-api</warName>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When build ... everything seems to be good.
But when i run server to deploy opm-api ... it cann't create been (class in opm-common)

Below is servlet-context.xml (in opm-api)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.chick.opm.common.model,com.chick.opm.common.service, com.chick.opm.api.controller, com.chick.opm.dao, com.chick.opm.api.service" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--    Service Common   -->
    <bean id="ResponeMessageService" class="com.chick.opm.common.service.iml.ResponeMessageServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="ConstantService" class="com.chick.opm.common.service.iml.ConstantService"></bean>
    <bean id="RouterService" class="com.chick.opm.common.service.iml.RouterService"></bean>

    <!--    Service     -->
    <bean id="CollectionService" class="com.chick.opm.api.service.partial.CollectionService"></bean>
    <bean id="CommonService" class="com.chick.opm.api.service.common.CommonService"></bean>

    <!--    DAO     -->
    <bean id="CollectionDAO" class="com.chick.opm.api.dao.CollectionDAO"></bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

Below is jboss-deployment-structure.xml (in opm-api)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <sub-deployment name="opm-common-0.1.1.war">
        <dependencies>
                  <module name="deployment.opm-common.war"/>
        </dependencies>
     </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Below is Error when deploy (have jboss-deployment-structure.xml )

```
11:40:39,668 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."opm-api.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."opm-api.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "opm-api.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0166: Sub deployment opm-common-0.1.1.war in jboss-deployment-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: 
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:190)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

11:40:39,985 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "opm-api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"opm-api.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"opm-api.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"opm-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0166: Sub deployment opm-common-0.1.1.war in jboss-deployment-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: "}}
11:40:42,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "opm-api.war" (runtime-name : "opm-api.war")
11:40:42,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."opm-api.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."opm-api.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "opm-api.war"
```

Comment: your opm-common.war is missing in the deployments hence it is not found at all.

Comment: opm-common.war already build success and it available in .m2 ... do I need to copy opm-common.war by hand into wildfly server

Comment: i suspect yes. try it